# Core Data best practice in creating table

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, core-data

I am trying to learn proper use of Core Data and I am wandering witch path is better.
I need object `Row` that have `n` dimension and `m` measurements, something like this :

```
n1 | n2 | n3 | n4 | .... | m1 | m2 | m3 | .....
-----------------------------------------------
```

My problem is that I don't know how much dimensions and measurements there will be. So my two solution is

1:

Create table whit 10 dimensions and 10 measurements:
This approach create a lot of `nill` values and have problem if there will be more then 10 dimension or measurement.
But for 1 million `Rows` you have 1 million data rows to fetch.

2:

Create table `Row` whit two relationships `Dimensions` and `Measurements`. This makes object Row whit sets dimension and measurements, so you avoid `nill` values and no problem whit number of dimensions and measurements. 
But for 1 million `Rows` you have at least 5 million datas (for example) to fetch and behind  there was some `joins` witch slows query down.

Witch approach is faster and better, for million `Rows`.

Comment: Second approach is the right one. Million objects seems to be a lot so read about core data performance https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/articles/cdPerformance.html

Comment: Thanks four your answer.